Do the paranasal sinuses change temperature upon waking?
I should preface this by saying that I've never been aware of having any sort of "sinus trouble", including headaches, though I'm certainly not immune to the normal symptoms of head colds.  But I notice that when waking in a cold room, I often hear a periodic ticking from paranasal sinuses on one or both sides expelling bubbles of air - superficially comparable to the ticking of a fishing reel with the bail loosened, perhaps.  There are perhaps two ticks a second for a minute or so; I think sometimes it starts before I'm conscious of being awake.  Presumably this reflects some change in blood flow that warms the air in some paranasal sinus or other.  They are well known to condition the temperature of air during breathing, and on consideration I suppose that by being at an intermediate temperature they can extract heat from the outgoing breath to warm incoming air.  But what is known of regulatory phenomena that suddenly changes the paranasal sinus temperature without a major change in ventilation rate?  I imagine such a phenomenon would be of very sharp interest to people who do get sinus headaches.

I don't understand what leads you to your theory. You're engaging in a lot of speculation with nothing to support your ideas. This question doesn't meet the prior research requirement.

@CareyGregory - well, what else would make me hear and (slightly) feel air bubbling from either side of my nasal cavity making a ticking sound right after waking up sometimes?. To be fair, I'll say I have tried breathing in through my nose rapidly, out through my mouth, to try to chill my sinuses, then reversed the process, without hearing so much as a single tick.  But it could be too well insulated for that to work, I think?

I don't know what else. I'm just trying to understand what you're basing your theory of sinus temperatures on other than speculation. I'm pretty sure there's published literature on this subject. Have you read any?

There are some paywalled abstracts that don't sound very surprising: paranasal sinuses normally maintain a constant temperature, at least in rabbits.  Surgery in rabbits or man reduces the temperature.  There's this paper, but, well, it is the sort of thing you read in Med Hypotheses.  (bellows pump for cooling the brain?  REALLY?)  Some detail on temperature changes may well be tucked away in an inaccessible paper somewhere that someone might remember.

Edit those links along with a relevant quote(s) into your question and it will be a much better question. It proves you did attempt to answer it yourself and that's all that's needed to meet the site's prior research requirement.
